# How to get a list of all files and files within directories using the ls command

Tags: shell

I am trying to get a list of all files within the directories and sub-directories but without using `find` or doing it recursively.

I need to find a way to do it using `ls`, `grep` and `sed`.

I can't seem to find a solution that doesn't just use `find`.

EDIT:

I am trying to basically find a way to count all the files and directories within one directory. I can't use recursive functions, but I can use iterative statements, such as for loops and if statements.

I have found a way to do this using a for loop, but this only searches within the subdirectories, and not within folders in those subdirectories. In other words the depth is only 2. I need it to search throughout. Again I cannot use the `find` command.

Hopefully this helps to clear out any issues.

This is what I have so far:

```
a=0
b=0
for i in $( ls ); do
    if [ -d "$i" ] ; then
        c=$(pwd)
        cd $i
        a=$(($a + $(ls -l | grep -e "^-" | wc -l)))
        b=$(($b + $(ls -l | grep -e "^d" | wc -l)))
        cd $c
    fi
done
echo "Number of files: $a"
echo "Number of directories: $b"
```

Comment: wondering why such limitations...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to avoid explicit recursion. `ls` was built just for that and has built-in recursion, use:

```
ls -R
```

Comment: I am trying to do it without any recursion at all, so I can't use ls -R, although I know that it is one solution to the problem

Comment: @Rikg09 the directory Tree is naturally recursive, an iterative solution is just an overcomplication

Comment: @Rikg09 How is `ls -R` "recursion" in this case? What sort of answer are you even looking for at this point?

Comment: Well that's what I thought ls -R did. On the manual is says that it lists the subdirectories recursively, so I can't use it. It is, by definition a recursive command isn't it?

Comment: @Caridorc The thing is, I need to do it iteratively... I've just edited my original question to show my progress with it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to execute iteratively a recursive task is to use some kind of stack (in this case an array):

```
DIR_COUNT=0
FILE_COUNT=0

# use an array as stack, initialized with the root dir 
STACK=(".")

# loop until the stack is empty
while [ ${#STACK[@]} -gt 0 ] ; do

    # get the next dir to process (first element of the array)
    DIR=${STACK[0]}

    # remove it from the stack (replace the stack with itself minus the first element)
    STACK=(${STACK[@]:1})

    for i in $(ls  $DIR); do
        if [ -d "$DIR/$i" ] ; then
            ((DIR_COUNT++))

            # add the directory to process it later
            STACK+=($DIR/$i)
        else
            ((FILE_COUNT++))
        fi
    done
done

echo Number of files: $FILE_COUNT
echo Number of directories: $DIR_COUNT
```

This will probably only work with `bash`, I hope this is ok.

Comment: This works perfectly, but I don't understand it. Would you be able to explain it to me? I am a novice with bash. Thanks so much

Comment: I have added a bit more comments. I hope this is clear enough, I am not a `bash` expert by any mean